# Is it normal if bean modifies it's property value in setter in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, gson, inversion-of-control

I am thinking how to code with Gson in Spring. Gson has various objects, which require "registering" of other objects, like [`registerTypeAdapter`](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#registerTypeAdapter(java.lang.reflect.Type,%20java.lang.Object)).

I imagined, that I can have `gsonBuilder` property in some singletons and that they can register themself's adapters in this property setter.

Another case is [`RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory`](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/extras/src/main/java/com/google/gson/typeadapters/RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.java?r=1141) which also requires to register subclasses in it. I could also have property for this class and have registering code inside setter.

The general question is if it is normal in IoC pattern to have "host" objects modify "value" objects in setters?

The situation is even worst because registering methods above have no unregistering counterparts. So, it would be expected, that setters are called only once.